# Android as bluetooth HID keyboard and Mouse?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, bluetooth-lowenergy, ndk-build

I have got android 4.4.4 with me with all root permission i wanted to make that device to work as Bluetooth HID mouse and keyboard.

I referred some of the resources from github and google code but i was not able to implement.

any help or idea would mean a lot to achieve this,Is there any ndk api or sample ndk app that can perform my task would be helpful.

**Note:
My device has got root capabilities.

My device is connected to bluetooth 4.0 dongle i have tested True Mouse/KB application which works fine with rooted device similar kind of feature i  want to implement.**

Thank you